# Moving the data of the database to a network drive

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I hope you can help me with my issue. So far i could not find any other queston tackling exactly my issue.
First I work on windows and iam new to mysql and mysql workbench.

I created my first Mysql DB locally and after working on it for a while my boss now asked me to grant other colleges access to it. But there is no "Server" for it in the common sense but only a network drive.

Now I want to move the database to just this network storage area (not create a server there or anything) and colleges should be able to just install Workbench (or phpmyadmin or an reporting tool) and easily connect to the db on the "server".

Is something like this possible and if so, how would I do it?

I read about some sql code examples and creating a dump but all of them seem to work with an actual server (I need to execute a command or sql code on the server). Which I dont have.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need to "move" the files to a network drive. The files without a server are not usefull. You need to install a MySql server (on your machine or in any other one) and grant access to your databases. Workbench or phpadmin are only tools to access easily to your MySql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create one common user, and give required grants.

The other users will install MySQL client/workbench and connect as a remote server.